# sql query to get max date of group

Tags: mysql

I want from each WishContent the newest date based on the wishContent.wishId So if I have wishContents like this:

```
ID   DATE
#1 : 09-03-2016
#1 : 08-03-2016
#1 : 03-04-2016
#2 : 09-02-2016
#2 : 04-01-2016
```

Then I only want:

```
#1 09-03-2016
#2 09-02-2016

SELECT
      wish.Status,
      wish.Id,
      wish.User,
      wish.CompletionDate,
      wishContent.Content,
      wishContent.Title,
      wishContent.Country,
      wishContent.City,
      wishContent.IsAccepted,
      wishContent.moderator_Username,
      MAX(wishContent.Date) AS max_date
      FROM `wish` JOIN wishContent on wish.Id = wishContent.wish_Id
      GROUP BY wish.Id where wish.Date
      ORDER BY max_date DESC
```

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html

Comment: WHERE normally goes before GROUP BY.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need an additional join to get the required result:

```sql
SELECT
      w.Status,
      w.Id,
      w.User,
      w.CompletionDate,
      wc.Content,
      wc.Title,
      wc.Country,
      wc.City,
      wc.IsAccepted,
      wc.moderator_Username,
      wcMax.max_date
      FROM wish AS w
      JOIN (SELECT wish_Id, MAX(wishContent.Date) AS max_date 
            FROM wishContent
            GROUP BY wish_Id
      ) AS wcMax ON w.Id = wcMax.wish_Id
      JOIN wishContent AS wc on wcMax.wish_Id = wc.wish_Id AND wc.Date = wcMax.max_date
      WHERE wish.Date
      ORDER BY max_date DESC
```

Comment: The following error occurs: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM wishContent
            GROUP BY wish_Id
      ) AS wcMAx ON w.Id = wcMax' at line 15

Comment: @M1Ö Sorry there was a typo in the query: I removed the `,` that was after `max_date`. Can you try again?

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT
      wish.Status,
      wish.Id,
      wish.User,
      wish.CompletionDate,
      wishContent.Content,
      wishContent.Title,
      wishContent.Country,
      wishContent.City,
      wishContent.IsAccepted,
      wishContent.moderator_Username,
      MAX(STR_TO_DATE(wishContent.Date,'%d-%m-%Y')) AS max_date
      FROM `wish` JOIN wishContent on wish.Id = wishContent.wish_Id
      GROUP BY wish.Id
     ) AS t
      ORDER BY t.max_date DESC;
```

I Assume your date format is dd-mm-yyyy.

Comment: @M1Ö I'm guessing you get the newest date, but you're looking for the content/title/country/city/isaccepted/moderator_username that go along with the latest entry too?